# Update panel conflicts with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have been using jQuery validation in submit click. My page contains two divs.

The problem arises when I place both the divs in single update panel, the validation stops working, the error shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

When update panel is commented, all works fine but with complete postback (which i don't want).

I have used almost all the things, i found on internet (noConflicts, Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(), etc.)

Can anyone help me more?

Code :

Head :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Javascript/Validators/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready
    (
      function () {
          jQuery("#btn_Save").live("click", function () {
              jQuery("#form1").validate
        (
          {
              rules: {
                  txtContactPerson: "required"
              },
              messages: {
                  txtContactPerson: " * Please enter Contact Person Name"
              }
          }
        );
          });
      }
    ); 
</script>
```

Body :

simple two listing divs in update panel

Comment: can you explain the significance of markup with sample?

Comment: Above query is edited with code sample, please help

Comment: In my experience trying to mix MS Ajax and jQuery with web-forms is full of "gotchas" like this. If you really want to use UpdatePanel then consider using standard ASP.NET validator controls. However, if you really want to use jQuery validation and Ajax then consider using the jQuery Form plug-in with a normal form (ie. no runat="server") that posts to a handler that processes the POST variables.

Comment: i cannot use form without runat="server", bcoz i m using gridview and asp:textbox in the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use jQuery validation with server forms. But it's become tricky whith UpdatePanel. Try approach below:

In header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
          $("#form1").validate(
          {
               rules: {
                    '<%= txtContactPerson.ClientID %>': "required"
               },
               messages: {
                    '<%= txtContactPerson.ClientID %>': " * Please enter Contact Person Name"
               }
          });
     })          
</script>
```

Right after ScriptManager control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(initializeRequestHandler);

     function initializeRequestHandler(sender, args) {
          if (args.get_postBackElement().id == '<%= btn_Save.ClientID %>' && $("#form1").valid() !== true) {
               args.set_cancel(true);
          }
     }
</script>
```

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContactPerson" />
          &nbsp;
          <asp:Button ID="btn_Save" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you want to disable async postback not only for `btn_Save` just remove this code: `args.get_postBackElement().id == '<%= btn_Save.ClientID %>' &&`

Comment: Its still not working, the errors showing are :
(1) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'    
(2) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'valid'

Comment: Validation plugin is not referenced. Check link to `jquery.validate.js` file and it's content. To be sure change src attribute to this one: 'http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/lib/jquery.js'

Comment: I changed the mentioned links, but still no success, both errors are still there. as per my understanding, there is nothing wrong with the validate.js script, bcoz it works fine immediately after removing update panel. if u can provide me your email, i can send you the pages and the files.

Comment: By the way, which framework version you are use? If it's 3.5 version try to change selector from `$("#form1")` to `$("#aspnetForm")`

Comment: i m using 3.5, $("#aspnetForm") also not working. I'll send you the copy of code soon...

Comment: hi yuriy, did u find my mail?

Comment: change form's id to `aspnetForm` and use script exactly as in answer, without `btn_Save` click handler